# subquery to find the customers that have placed an order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have just started learning MYSQL and while I am very good with joins, I am having lots of problems with subqueries. So I have decided to practice more. 
I want to find the customers and their id, who have placed an order in the past. The item's price must be $6.5 or higher. Using joins this is how I have done it:

```
SELECT 
CUSTOMER_TBL.CUST_ID
, CUST_NAME
FROM 
CUSTOMER_TBL
INNER JOIN ORDERS_TBL
ON ORDERS_TBL.CUST_ID = CUSTOMER_TBL.CUST_ID
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS_TBL 
ON ORDERS_TBL.PROD_ID = PRODUCTS_TBL.PROD_ID
WHERE PRODUCTS_TBL.COST > 6.5
```

Here is how I have done using subquery.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_TBL.CUST_ID
, CUST_NAME
FROM CUSTOMER_TBL
WHERE 
EXISTS (
SELECT * 
FROM ORDERS_TBL
WHERE ORDERS_TBL.CUST_ID = CUSTOMER_TBL.CUST_ID
)
```

As you can see I got up to the part of including only those who have placed an order. But I cannot figure out the rest; of orders, only those that were higher than $6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CUST_ID, CUST_NAME FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE
WHERE CUST_ID IN
(SELECT CUST_ID FROM ORDERS_TBL 
WHERE PROD_ID IN 
(SELECT PROD_ID FROM PRODUCTS_TBL
WHERE COST > 6.5))
```

This might help you.

Comment: It certainly does. You took a different, yet much simpler approach. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah but always go for join if possible. This has got some performance issues.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have heard. I personally prefer joins anyway, so I will.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe:

```
SELECT 
  CUSTOMER_TBL.CUST_ID,
  CUST_NAME
FROM 
  CUSTOMER_TBL
WHERE EXISTS 
(
   SELECT 
     * 
   FROM 
     ORDERS_TBL
     INNER JOIN PRODUCTS_TBL 
        ON ORDERS_TBL.PROD_ID = PRODUCTS_TBL.PROD_ID
     WHERE 
        ORDERS_TBL.CUST_ID = CUSTOMER_TBL.CUST_ID
        AND PRODUCTS_TBL.COST > 6.5
)
```

Comment: This does work, but what I had in mind was not using any kind of joins at all. For the sake of practice, you know. Nevertheless I am appreciated for your quick response.